# Regular expression with quotes

Tags: regex, autoit

I got some troubles finding the good Regexp. 
I got this text as Input :

```
settings= ShouldAppears1
setting_ -> "ShouldAppears2"
setting__ = 'ShouldAppears3' #ShouldNotAppear
setting___ = "MissingEndQuote.ShouldNotAppears
```

As a result I would like to get an array with :

```
[0] =>  settings=ShouldAppears1
[1] =>  settings=ShouldAppears2 or [1] =>  settings="ShouldAppears2"
[2] =>  settings=ShouldAppears3 or [2] =>  settings="ShouldAppears3"
```

I got some troubles because I don't want a result if there is a missing end quote and I can't find a back reference working.

What I got so far is this regexp:

```
(?i)([A-Z_]{3,}\s{0,1}[=><-]{1,2}\s{0,1}(['"]?).+?\2)
```

Problem is that I got this output:

```
0 => settings= A
1 => 
2 => setting_ = "Appears"
3 => "
4 => setting__ = "Appears"
5 => "
6 => setting___ = "
7 =>
```

I would like to not see the lines 1,3,5,7 but I can't do a (?=) non capturing group but still be able to use the back reference.

Thanks for your help,

**EDIT**

I can't really change how the regexp is called in the script I can only work on the Regexp. The result is only the Global Match, not the Global Full Match. If I change a little your regexp by :

```
(?i)(\w+\s*(?:=|->)\s*(?:("|')\w+\g{2}|\w+))
```

I get

```
0 => settings= ShouldAppears1
1 => setting_ -> "ShouldAppears2"
2 => "
3 => setting__ = 'ShouldAppears3'
4 => '
```

It's almost perfect but is there a way to get rid of the [2] and [4]? Ie set the ("|') not captured but still be able to back reference to it?

Answer (score 1):

If you can use back-reference:

```
(?i)(\w+)\s*(?:=|->)\s*(("|')\w+\g{3}|\w+)
```

Capturing Group 0 matches the whole key-value pair.
Capturing Group 1 matches the key.
Capturing Group 2 matches the value.
Capturing Group 3 matches the quote,double quote or nothing

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What I would is to have only the group 0. I Edit my post to make you understand better